# Python program and regex

Tags: regex, python-2.7

Would you be so kind to help me with some regex and Python code? I have recently received a lot of help for a Python script to go through some firewall logs. I am almost there, but still need a little help.

Here some log output from a firewall:

```
Nov 11 00:00:09 firewall %ASA-3-710003: TCP access denied by ACL from 1.1.1.1/50624 to internet:2.2.2.2/80
Nov  6 12:42:23 firewall %ASA-4-106023: Deny tcp src inside:3.3.3.3/42059 dst internet:4.4.4.4/389 by access-group "access_out" [0x0, 0x0]
```

The logs can both have IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. I need to extract the protocol (tcp|udp|icmp), source_ip, the destination_ip, the destination_port and a counter for each unique line. But as you can see from the two above lines, the log output is different in the two lines, e.g. in one line the protocol is written in uppercase, the other in lowercase, and also different text in between the IP addresses. I am able to get the correct output from one of the lines but not both.

```
prot   source                    destination               port   hitcnt
------ ------------------        ------------------        ------ ------------------
tcp    1111:2222:0:abcd::12      2222:3333:0:efab::101     389    180
tcp    2222:3333:0:efab::50      1111:2222:0:abcd::12      389    29
ump    1111:4444:0:1111::2       1111:2222:0:abcd::12      123    4
tcp    1.1.1.1                   3.3.3.3                   23     4
imp    2.2.2.2                   4.4.4.4                          4
```

The code from python script looks like this (thanks to holroy)

```
import re       #for regular expressions - to match ip's
import sys      #for parsing command line opts
from collections import Counter

DENY_PATTERN = re.compile(r'Deny\s(?P<protocol>.+?)\ssrc.*?:(?P<src>[0-9a-f\.]*)/?.*?\s.*?dst.*?:(?P<dst>[0-9a-f\.]*)((/(?P<dst_port>[0-9]*)\s)|\s)')

LINE_FORMAT='{0:<6.6} {1:<25.25} {2:<25.25} {3:<6.6} {4}'

def process_log_file(log file):
    """Reads through the log_file, and returns a counter based on Deny-lines."""

    # Process file line by line
    with open(logfile, 'r') as data :
        seen = Counter()

        # find all Deny line and append them in a list
        for line in data :
            # If line has 'Deny ' in it, then check it some more
            if 'Deny ' in line :
                seen.update(DENY_PATTERN.findall(line)) 
    return seen

def print_counter(counter):
    """Pretty print the result of the counter."""

    print(LINE_FORMAT.format('prot', 'source', 'destination',  'port', 'hitcnt'))
    print(LINE_FORMAT.format(*tuple(('------------------',) * 5)))
    for (protocol, src, dst, _, _, dst_port), count in counter.most_common():
        print(LINE_FORMAT.format(protocol, src, dst, dst_port, count))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # if file is specified on command line, parse, else ask for file
    if sys.argv[1:] : 
        print "File: %s" % (sys.argv[1])
        logfile = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        logfile = raw_input("Please enter a file to parse, e.g /var/log/secure: ")

    denial_counter = process_log_file(logfile)
    print_counter(denial_counter)
```

I've tried a lot of regex combinations (e.g. https://regex101.com/r/wC6gS7/2, but am not able to get output right.

Also if I try with an or (|) between two regex, I am not able to call it `(?P<protocol>)` in both the regex since it has already been used. If I use a DENY_PATTERN and DENY_PATTERN2 with each regex and call it like this it also doesn't work:

```
for line in data :
    if 'Deny ' in line :
        seen.update(DENY_PATTERN.findall(line)) 

for line in data :
    if 'ASA-3 ' in line :
        seen.update(DENY_PATTERN2.findall(line))
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi again @joni, this question is a much better fit here, and if you want we can discuss some aspects related to this question in a [char room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31653/a-python-room-for-me-and-joni) I've created...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Testing multiple patterns

To test for multiple complex pattern, you'll want to add those tests within the one and only loop through your data file. That is you want the following code:

```
    for line in data :

        # If line has 'Deny ' in it, then check it some more
        if 'Deny ' in line:
            seen.update(DENY_PATTERN.findall(line)) 

        # If line has 'ASA-3' in it, then check for the other pattern
        if 'ASA-3' in line:
            seen.update(DENIED_PATTERN.findall(line))
```

This way you read through the file one time, and only do the heavier pattern matching if the basic test against `Deny` or `ASA-3` has already occured.

### Regexp comments

In your regexp you have a few extra groups, which are not needed, and you test against `[A-Z].*?`, which is *one* uppercase character, followed by a non-greedy match of anything. Unless that is specific what you are after, it would be better to use `[A-Z]*?` (or `[A-Za-z]*?`) to match for a sequence of characters. I took the liberty of saving a few extra version, ending with the following (see https://regex101.com/r/wC6gS7/8):

```
DENIED_PATTERN = re.compile(r'''
    :\s+?                                   # Start with leading white space
    (?P<protocol>[A-Z]*?)                   # Capture "<protocol>" start
    \saccess\s+denied\s+by\s+ACL\s+from\s+  # Matches literal string
    (?P<src>[0-9a-f\.:]*)/.*?:              # Captures "<src>" plus extra text
    (?P<dst>[0-9a-f\.:]*)                   # Captures "<dst>"
    (?:/(?P<dst_port>[0-9]*?))?\s           # Optional captures "/<dst_port>" 
    ''', re.X)
```

Note also that using the `re.X` (or `re.VERBOSE`) can drastically increase the understanding of your patterns. Using this flag you can include whitespace and end of line comments using `#`.

Using `(?: ... )` is a nice construct to create a group, which can be made optional by adding a `?`, like in `(?:/(?P<dst_port>[0-9]+))?`. This would optionally capture stuff like "/80". Note however that since it is now made optional, I added a `\s` to satisify the greadiness of earlier constructs, as it otherwise could be left out.

Regarding alternate groups, they are often useful to construct using the non-capturing group construct, like in `(?: ... | ... | ...)`. But be aware that you if combined with named capture groups, the names needs to be unique.

### Changes to `print_counter()`

As the number of captured groups varies in the two patterns, there is a need to modify the print out, as well. To differentiate between the two patterns you could either depend upon the count of captured groups, or you could introduce an identifier into your match groups. I.e. you could extend the regexp's to include `Deny` and `ASA-3`.

I chose to use the number of capture groups. As now the number of capture groups varies in the for loop this poses a slight issue with expanding the tuple directly as you either have too many or too few elements to unpack. The solution to this is to delay the expansion a little. This ends up with the following code:

```
def print_counter(counter):
    """Pretty print the result of the counter."""

    print(LINE_FORMAT.format('prot', 'source', 'destination',  'port', 'hitcnt'))
    print(LINE_FORMAT.format(*tuple(('------------------',) * 5)))
    for re_match, count in counter.most_common():

        re_match_length = len(re_match)

        # Pick elements based on match from DENY_PATTERN        
        if re_match_length == 8:
            protocol, src, src_port, dst, dst_port, icmp_spec, icmp_type, icmp_code =  re_match
            if icmp_code or icmp_type:
                dst_port = '{}, {}'.format(icmp_code, icmp_type)

        # Pick elements based on match from DENIED_PATTERN
        if re_match_length == 4:
            protocol, src, dst, dst_port = re_match


        print(LINE_FORMAT.format(protocol.lower(), src, dst, dst_port, count))
```

To beautify the output a bit, I added a `protocol.lower()` so that they are always presented in lowercase. This could also have been done within the corresponding `if` statement, along side with other needed tweaking before outputting the line.